# How to fix bottom of door frame (light puppy chewing)

Tags: doors

So I live in a rented apartment and some things did not go as planned and ended up with a puppy before moving instead of after. Anyways I just noticed he has been chewing on the frame inside my bedroom and I'm just wondering how to fix this so I can obtain as much of my deposit as possible

Comment: A picture would really help here.

Comment: Which part of the frame is damaged? Is only the casing damaged, or is the jamb damaged as well? Photos will help.

Comment: Wood filler is probably the answer, but a picture would help a lot.

Comment: See the linked post and its answers, and if your situation is different, please add details to your question to explain how. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Answer (score -2):

Spray it with a very light water solution of cayenne pepper after perfectly sculpting & restoring the frame to new condition with wood putty & sanding &  priming & painting accordingly. Get the pup more or some chew toys & approved rawhide bones to address the teething issues...one's that hold treats will make the pup forget about the door frame.